# How to reset the emulator size in Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation

I accedintly resized my android emulater, and now it is shrinked. I tried deleting the emulator and then adding again but it remains the same. The problem is the image shown is too blurry.
[image: Blurry image of the app]

[image: Another blurry image]

Comment: You should be able to resize emulator screen just like a regular window, by click holding at bottom corner and stretching

Answer (score 0):

You can now you can resize your window simply by dragging a corner.

[image]